# Cannot run virtualenvwrapper on MacOs

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, virtualenvwrapper

I've tried to run virtualenvwrapper on mac (high sierra 10.13.4) but got this error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have installed with pip following the [docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) but nothing seems to work :/

And the curious thing is that the file `virtualenvwrapper.sh` exists in the mentioned directory:

```
lem4fia@MBP-de-Bruno ~ $ ls /usr/local/bin
```

[image]

I have trid to uninstall and re-install virtualenvwrapper but the same issue still happens.

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/bin`? `head -1 /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`? `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/bin` reveals that virtualenvwrapper.sh points to (?) another path:

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 lem4fia  admin        58 26 Mai 17:50 virtualenvwrapper.sh -> /Users/lem4fia/Library/Python/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

if i source this path returns the same error:

`-bash: /Users/lem4fia/Library/Python/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory`

the other commands you have mentioned returns the same error too

Comment: Does the file `/Users/lem4fia/Library/Python/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` exist?

Comment: No, should i move/copy the file to that location or this would be a "mcgyver" trick?

Answer (score 18):

Ok i've fixed this issue by doing this:

`pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper`

the uninstall will ask if i want to proceed, but the first line shows the correct path to `virtualenvwrapper.sh` since the location changes from OS to OS and version to version, i've copied the path and answered no to keep virtualenvwrapper installed, and then pasted the correct path to `.bash_profile`.

After this i've got an error saying that virtualenvwrapper could not find the virtualenv, but fixed it by uninstalling and installing again the virtualenv with pip.

Comment: +1 very useful, in my case, I am using `pyenv`, so the path was `/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Comment: In my case, I installed Python with Homebrew on macOS Monterey and the path (echoed by `pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper`) was /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh